# Terminal command to change permissions to my 'Sites' folder and apply change to enclosed items?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, permissions, file-permissions

Using Snow Leopard, I'm having issues with permissions in my Sites folder. While I can navigate to `localhost/~username` and read any files or folders there, the same permissions have not been applied to enclosed items, and I get a 403 error trying to access them in the browser.

If I select one of these enclosed folders and get info using Finder, I see the user 'Everyone' is set to 'No Access' but I can't change that (this behavior seems buggy, actually).

And if I select my 'Sites' folder, the tool to 'Apply to enclosed items' is grayed out...

Is there a Terminal command I can use to grant 'Read Only' access to my Sites folder, and all it contains, for the user 'Everyone'?

Answer (score 2):

Since OSX is BSD-ish, try

```
chmod -R o+r Sites
```

Your directories will need:

```
chmod o+x [whatever directories]
```

Without a Mac at hand, you might be able to do the above by:

```
find Sites -type d -exec chmod o+x \{} \;
```

which will find all of the directories under Sites and allow 'others' to enter the directory.

Comment: combine the first two into `chmod -R o+rX Sites`. The capital X option will only add execute/search permission for files which already have it set for some user.